# filter rows with correct index from another dataframe

Tags: indexing

I have two dataframes (numbers are index)

df1:

84   this is a dog
95   the boy is running
23   baby is crying
2    the place is beautiful
43   the road is not good
66   the tv is on

df2:

0   baby is crying
1   the road is not good
2   this is a dog

I want a new dataframe df3 like this:

23  baby is crying
43  the road is not good
84   this is a dog